# Error toDate() InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert Timestamp.. Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following field in Firestore:
[image]

When I try to get it in my application, for example:

`<p>{{ fechaInicio | date }}</p>`
Get the following error:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert
>   "Timestamp(seconds=1553230800, nanoseconds=0)" into a date' for pipe
>   'DatePipe'

then I saw that adding `toDate()` supposedly fixes the problem:

`<p>{{ fechaInicio.toDate() | date }}</p>`

This shows the date correctly, however I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined

How can I solve that?

Comment: is the variable fechaInicio loaded asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, asynchronously

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like the variable 'fechaInicio' loads asynchronously. If so, 'fechaInicio' remains undefined till it get updated. Therefore, what you can do is hiding the html paragraph until the data get loaded to the variable.

Try the following modification.

```
<p *ngIf="fechaInicio">{{ fechaInicio.toDate() | date }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked !. The explanation is very interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Just place a `?` after `fechaInicio` like:

```
<p>{{ fechaInicio?.toDate() | date }}</p>
```